# Iterate over object fields which can be another object

Tags: java, spring, reflection

Is there a nice way to iterate over object fields using reflection?
The main problem is in object can be another object therefore it's needed to iterate over another object's properties too.

For example I have AllInclusiveDetails object

```
public class AllInclusiveDetails {
   
   @JsonProperty("renters_business")
   private String rentersBusiness;

   @Valid
   @NotNull
   @JsonProperty("main_property_owner_details")
   private ShortCustomer mainPropertyOwnerDetails;

   @Valid
   @NotNull
   @JsonProperty("main_tenant_details")
   private ShortCustomer mainTenantDetails;
}
```

And ShortCustomer is

```
public class ShortCustomer {

  @NotNull
  @Positive
  private Long id;

  @NotEmpty
  @JsonProperty("full_name")
  private String fullName;

  @JsonProperty("organization_number")
  private String organizationNumber;

  @PastOrPresent
  private LocalDate birthdate;

}
```

I want to iterate over AllInclusiveDetails object fields using reflection and if there is another object in it , I want to iterate over that object fields too.

The main purpose is to track if value of the same field in two different object are equal or not and if not to save old value and the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Does this satisfy your requirement:

```
for(Field field : AllInclusiveDetails.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
        if(field.getType()== ShortCustomer.class) {
            //Do your logic here
        }
    }
```

Comment: The main difficulty is that this AllInclusiveDetails object contains too many another objects and I would like to create some generic decision for this issue

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to get all the fields of a class and a method to recursively use reflection to compare fields. Play around with `main` to test it, it will not work correctly for Objects that are logically equivalent but not the same in memory.

```
// Gathers all fields of this class, including those in superclasses, regardless of visibility
public static List<Field> getAllFields(Class<?> klass) {
    List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Class<?> k = klass; k != null; k = k.getSuperclass()) {
        fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(k.getDeclaredFields()));
    }
    return fields;
}
```

---

```
// Uses reflection and recursion to deep compare two objects.
// If the sub-fields and sub-arrays are not deeply equal this will return false.
// This will cause problems with data structures that may be logically equivalent
// but not have the same structure in memory, HashMaps and Sets come to mind
//
// Also might perform illegal reflective access which gets a warning from the JVM
// WARNING: Illegal reflective access ... to field java.util.LinkedList.size
// WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers ...
// WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
// WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
public static <T> boolean reflexiveEquals(T o1, T o2) {
    return reflexiveEquals(o1, o2, new HashSet<>(), new HashSet<>());
}
private static <T> boolean reflexiveEquals(T o1, T o2, Set<Object> o1Refs, Set<Object> o2Refs) {
    if (o1 == o2) {
        // exact same object or both are null
        return true;
    }
    if (o1 == null || o2 == null) {
        // one is null but the other is not
        System.err.println(o1 + " != " + o2);
        return false;
    }

    Class<?> type = o1.getClass();
    if (type != o2.getClass()) {
        // not the exact same class therefore not equal
        // you could treat this differently if you want
        System.err.println(type + " != " + o2.getClass());
        return false;
    }

    if (PRIMITIVE_WRAPPERS.contains(type)) {
        // if it's a primitive wrapper then compare plainly
        boolean result = Objects.equals(o1, o2);
        if (!result) {
            System.err.println("Objects.equals: " + o1 + " : " + o2);
        }
        return result;
    }

    // before descending, make sure there wont be an infinite loop
    // if this object appeared in the reference chain before
    // then it is currently being compared lower in the stack,
    // return true to let it finish it's comparison
    if (o1Refs.contains(o1) || o2Refs.contains(o2)) {
        return true;
    }

    try {
        // keep track of the objects that have been descended into
        o1Refs.add(o1);
        o2Refs.add(o2);

        if (type.isArray()) {
            // if its an array, compare all elements
            try {
                Object[] a1 = (Object[]) o1;
                Object[] a2 = (Object[]) o2;
                // only comparable field besides elements
                if (a1.length != a2.length) {
                    System.err.println("Array length diff");
                    return false;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
                    if (!reflexiveEquals(a1[i], a2[i], o1Refs, o2Refs)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // otherwise its some other object so compare all fields
        // moving up the super-classes as well
        for (Class<?> k = type; k != null; k = k.getSuperclass()) {
            for (Field f : k.getDeclaredFields()) {
                try {
                    f.setAccessible(true);
                    if (!reflexiveEquals(f.get(o1), f.get(o2), o1Refs, o2Refs)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    } finally {
        // remove the references since their compare is complete
        o1Refs.remove(o1);
        o2Refs.remove(o2);
    }
}
```

---

```
private static final Set<Class<?>> PRIMITIVE_WRAPPERS = getPrimitiveWrapperClasses();
private static final Set<Class<?>> getPrimitiveWrapperClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.add(Boolean.class);
    set.add(Character.class);
    set.add(Byte.class);
    set.add(Short.class);
    set.add(Integer.class);
    set.add(Long.class);
    set.add(Float.class);
    set.add(Double.class);
    set.add(Void.class);
    return set;
}
```

---

```
public static class AllInclusiveDetails {
    private String rentersBusiness;
    private ShortCustomer mainPropertyOwnerDetails;
    private ShortCustomer mainTenantDetails;
    private ShortCustomer[] arr;
    private List<ShortCustomer> list;
}

public static class ShortCustomer {
    private Long id;
    private String fullName;
    private String organizationNumber;
    private LocalDate birthdate;
}
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AllInclusiveDetails aids1 = new AllInclusiveDetails();
    aids1.rentersBusiness = "Business";
    aids1.mainTenantDetails = new ShortCustomer();
    aids1.mainTenantDetails.id = 1L;
    aids1.mainTenantDetails.fullName = "John Doe";
    aids1.arr = new ShortCustomer[] {
            aids1.mainTenantDetails,
            aids1.mainPropertyOwnerDetails };
    aids1.list = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(aids1.arr));

    AllInclusiveDetails aids2 = new AllInclusiveDetails();
    aids2.rentersBusiness = "Business";
    aids2.mainTenantDetails = new ShortCustomer();
    aids2.mainTenantDetails.id = 1L;
    aids2.mainTenantDetails.fullName = "John Doe";
    aids2.arr = new ShortCustomer[] {
            aids2.mainTenantDetails,
            aids2.mainPropertyOwnerDetails };
    aids2.list = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(aids2.arr));

    System.out.println(reflexiveEquals(aids1, aids2));
}
```